# Does bash exploit (CVE-2014-6271) require terminal access to utilize?

Tags: bash, exploit, shellshock-bash-bug

With all the scare regarding CVE-2014-6271, I've found little concrete information regarding the vulnerability's surface area.  In particular, does an individual require terminal access to execute this exploit?  I am aware that CGI services that call out to the shell can indirectly provide access to this vulnerability (as per [The bash vulnerability CVE-2014-6271 . Can it affect my CGI perl scripts? How to understand this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038053/the-bash-vulnerability-cve-2014-6271-can-it-affect-my-cgi-perl-scripts-how-to)), but what other vectors of attack exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, looks like apache's mod_cgi and mod_cgid are gateways for bash environment code execution with a crafted HTTP request header.

Comment: I do see this confirmed now that I know what to look for.  I appreciate the feedback.